# extract an mumber from array

Tags: php, arrays, object, moodle

In mooodle I create a course via web service the output of array that I print via command print_r is:

```
 [{"id":29,"shortname":"math1"}]
```

I wanna to extract just 29 of this text via PHP
how can id do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to do this you have to `decode` the array:

```
<?php

$json_array = ' [{"id":29,"shortname":"math1"}]';
$php_array = json_decode($json_array);
echo $php_array[0]->id;
```

And you can do a `foreach` loop if there is more data

Sandbox [link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/55443ebd2a85b7ff5ad6f07f54cdd8c3c581c1cf)

Comment: Its worth noting that if the string fails to decode, this will produce an error. It might be better to protect against that.

Comment: @WesleySmith True, he must check the array before echo or print, he know the logic now, its better to use `foreach` instead of using `[0]` and must check for empty or null array